# Why pressing TAB key (:focus effect) causes positioned off-the-screen <div> element with <input> field inside it to appear on the screen?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, viewport

[image]

I would like to know, why after pressing `TAB key` on div container with negative margin-right (`margin-right:-170px`) that contains focusable element (input, hyperlink) is being shown on the screen? Any ideas?

In my case I need to **prevent such a behaviour** since I've sidebar menu (off the screen), which is shown after user press tab button several times. And it shouldn't. I want to show this sidebar only on mobile and tablet devices.

**Note:** What's more. The **behaviour is different** in `Firefox` and different in `Google Chrome`. In my example if you remove `<input>` element and leave only hyperlink `<a>`, the box will NOT show after pressing tab key. In Chrome it will.

**Similar post:** [Chrome bug? or how do I prevent a form field to SCROLL the container when focused?](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/chrome-bug-or-how-do-i-prevent-a-form-field-to-scroll-the-container-when-focused)

**One of solutions (preventing TAB):**
May resolve the problem, but not recommended.

```
    $("body").on("keydown",  function (e) {
        if (e && e.keyCode === 9) {
            console.log('Tab was pressed', e);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

**>> Working example from the screenshot:**

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  margin-right:-170px; /* Negative margin to set container off the screen*/
  padding:10px;
  background: #292929;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)
}

.box.input {
    top: 0;
}

.box.hyperlink {
    top: 100px;
}

body {
  background: lightgray;
}

a {
  color: white;
}
input {
  margin:10px 15px;
}
p {
  width:400px;
  }
```

```html
<p>After you press TAB key, box containing input will appear from the right on the screen.... but why?</p>

<div class="box input">
  <label>Custom Input 1</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="some input" />
</div>         

<div class="box hyperlink">
  <label>Custom hyperlink</label>
  <a href="http://www.apple.com" target="_blank">Some link</a>
</div>
```

**>> Working example #2**

http://jsfiddle.net/pndz/yy9kzp3e/

Comment: Pressing the Tab key focuses the link and the browser scrolls/moves the element so that the user can see the link otherwise focusing it wouldn't make sense. There are probably several ways to avoid that, but IMHO the main problem is that you are using a negative margin to hide the element. Is there a special reason you are using that instead of something such as `display: none`?

Comment: 1. I can see that browser scrolls/moves to input, but how exactly is it happening (what happens under the hood)? Does browser add any special styles and if yes, what styles are applied? 

2. In my case I used negative margin-right, to get this nice animation with slide from the right (when entering / closing). If I 'use display:none;' it wouldn't work.

Comment: If you letting it slide in, you could have it slide in when the link gets focus.

Comment: Sure I could... but I'm still curious why this is happening in the first place. There are several workarounds this issue, but I hope someone could explain this strange browser bahaviour....

Comment: It don't see this as strange, but normal browser behavior: Tab is traditionally used to navigate between links in browsers - just like tab is used to navigate between input elements in normal desktop programs. And if the element is off-screen the browser scrolls to display it. The same happens when the link is on a longer page below the bottom border of the browser window.

Comment: Have you tried using absolute positioning instead of a negative margin?

Comment: Yes, same effect if you set: position: absolute;right: -150px;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a `tabIndex` of `-1` to prevent tab focusability to elements that you don't want to gain focus with the tab key.

Comment: Héhé, thanks for this quick little hack, this *temporarily* solves my issue. :smirk:

Comment: It's not a hack @Gregordy, that's a HTML feature to allow engineers to control what can be tab-focused and what can't.

Comment: Yes I understand. The whole story is that in my case it's kind of a hack as tabbing on a particular element applies styles that break my design. And because I have no idea where these styles come from and couldn't figure out how to remove them, I simply "prevented tabbing on my element".

Answer (score 6):

Setting your `.box` to `fixed` instead of `absolute` prevents the behavior.

```
.box {
    /* ... */
    position: fixed; /* position the element relative to the viewport */
    /* ... */
}
```

I assume because the browser can't scroll "beyond the viewport". It's also the more intuitive semantic if your intention is to position the element *off the screen*.

---

If the sidebar is only meant for small devices I agree with the notion that it's more clean to not display it at all on other devices. e.g.

```
@media all and (min-width: 769px) { /* determining the correct size is up to you */
    .box {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

*but please be aware that viewport with is actually not a very reliable way of detecting 'small devices'*

### Explanation

The box is placed inside your `<body>` which expands to hold the content (made obvious by the horizontal scrollbar). When pressing tab gives focus to the `<input>`, the browser scrolls the focused element into view. So actually not the box but the entire element content is moving left. Technically speaking the `scrollLeft` Property of the containing node (`<body>` in your case) is set such that the input is visible on the screen.

*This is from a Chromium point of view, finer implementation details can vary between browsers.*

Comment: Fixed is bad for mobile, it could lead to several bugs, even on iOS 10..

Answer (score 0):

one simple and best way to handle this with CSS, is to use CSS display property.
eg:

```
 .slider-content .items:not(.active) {
    display: none;
}
```

For other slides that are not active.
Thanks ~RDaksh